# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Trying to remove an item with broken URL from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-glide

I'm loading a list of URLs using Glide as follows :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(arrayList.get(position))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .error(R.drawable.transparent_icon)
            .override(Constants.THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Constants.THUMBNAIL_SIZE)
            .fitCenter()
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    isBrokenUrl = true;

                  
                    arrayList.remove(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition());  //ISSUE IS HERE
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition(), getItemCount());

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    isBrokenUrl = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(holder.image);

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(v -> itemStringClickListener.onItemClicked(arrayList.get(position)));
}
```

In the list there are a broken URL, I would like to remove the item with these broken url from `RecyclerView` :

```
                    arrayList.remove(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition(), getItemCount());
```

It's work, but if I scroll too fast, the app crash with :

```
 com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.CallbackException: Unexpected exception thrown by non-Glide code
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.callCallbackOnLoadFailed(EngineJob.java:175)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$CallLoadFailed.run(EngineJob.java:402)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7889)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=109; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:506)
        at maa.utils.adapters.SearchedStickersAdapter$1.onLoadFailed(SearchedStickersAdapter.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onLoadFailed(SingleRequest.java:683)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onLoadFailed(SingleRequest.java:651)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.callCallbackOnLoadFailed(EngineJob.java:173)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$CallLoadFailed.run(EngineJob.java:402) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7889) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code failed because getBindingAdapterPosition returned -1.  That view holder wasn't bound to any position.  It seems like you're trying to do something asynchronous here.  If so, you should NOT be passing the view holder or any of the views in it to any callbacks.  Instead, you should pass the position and/or the data item at that index when you make the asynchronous call, and NOT query the holder during the callback.  This is because the binding can change between then and when the callback occurs.  If you don't do it that way, even when it "works" it may be performing actions on the wrong index.

Actually since you're doing this in onBindViewHolder, replacing that with just `position` in both places you use it should make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact, I use `holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()` because Android studio shows a warning message with this : **Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later**

Comment: However, I've fixed the issue with another strategy, I will accept your answer in case someone faced the same issue

Comment: They're talking about in a different context.  Inside the holder, you should not treat position as fixed-  you should not assume that the holder is always bound to the same index.  If for example you has an onClickEventListener in there, that should use holder.getBindingAdapterPosition(), or they'd need to be recreated on every bind.  Your callbacks aren't dealing with the holder, they're dealing with the raw data.  That means they should do the exact opposite.

Comment: massive thanks for taking time to give me this information